# How can i style the Image in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I want to make a graphic like in the picture, but because I can't style the picture, I can't give simple properties like border radius. I tried to do it by trying the child selectors but it didn't work. Do you have any advice for me to do this?

**Note:** I tried to do it with parent div, but there's a gap between the image and the border and i couldn't figure it out.

```
import styles from '/src/styles/Demo.module.css';
...
   <div className='graphImg'>
      <Image src={Grag} objectFit='cover'/>
   </div>
```

and my css

```
.graphImg > div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border-color: #54595F70;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPao2.png)

Answer (score 0):

first use width and height in image

```
import styles from '/src/styles/Demo.module.css';
<div className={styles.graphImg}>
      <Image src={Grag} width={300} height={200} />
   </div>
```

and for css

```
.graphImg img {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border-color: #54595F70;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

if not work use  "!important" for css